# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following: if

Tags: plsql

I should print India and Israel in caps and all other countries in lower case.

I am getting the following error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the
>   following: if

How can I index this array to display the countries in alphabetical order?

```
DECLARE
   type idtable IS TABLE OF COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE;
   type nametable IS TABLE OF COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE;
   idtab idtable;
   nametab nametable;
   total INTEGER;

   CURSOR c1 IS
   SELECT country_id, country_name
   FROM countries; 

BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO idtab, nametab;
  CLOSE c1;


  for i =1 in nametab.FIRST .. nametab.LAST LOOP
    IF (nametab(i)) = 'India' 
      THEN dbms_output.put_line(UPPER((nametab(i))));
      ELSIF (nametab(i)) = 'Israel'
      THEN dbms_output.put_line(UPPER((nametab(i))));
      ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (nametab(i));
  END LOOP;

  END;
```

Comment: Your block is correct except only one mistake. Unlike C or C++ loops, in PLSQL you need not have to initialize it. So i =1 in for loop is wrong. Remove '=1' and it should work fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
   TYPE idtable IS TABLE OF COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE;

   TYPE nametable IS TABLE OF COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE;

   idtab     idtable;
   nametab   nametable;
   total     INTEGER;

   CURSOR c1
   IS
      SELECT country_id, country_name FROM countries;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;

   FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO idtab, nametab;

   CLOSE c1;

   FOR i IN nametab.FIRST .. nametab.LAST
   LOOP
      IF (nametab (i)) = 'India' THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (UPPER ( (nametab (i))));
      ELSIF (nametab (i)) = 'Israel' THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (UPPER ( (nametab (i))));
      ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (nametab (i));
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```